Calculating Z-score between two distributions with errors, to have an indication of how much the two sets are comparable
This sounds like an obvious question and, most certainly, it has been asked many times before. However, I didn't manage to find anything here nor elsewhere.
I have two vectors of $n$ values; let them be called vec1 and vec2. Each of them represents $n$ measurements of the same thing, for example an estimate of the gravity constant, but vec1 and vec2 follow two distinct derivations.
Hence, vec1 has mean $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$ and vec2 has mean $\mu_2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_2$, which we assume to be different since the calculations and the equipment use are assumed to be different.
Suppose the two distributions do in fact plot two Gaussian curves. What can be an index  of how "close" are the two Gaussians, hence how precise and accurate they are?
My idea was to use a modified kind of $Z$-score:
$$
\tilde{Z} = \frac{|\mu_1 - \mu_2 |}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2}
$$
or
$$
\tilde{Z} = \frac{|\mu_1 - \mu_2 |}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}
$$
but I couldn't find anything that justifies this formula.

It sounds like you are looking for a two sample z-test: https://www.analystsoft.com/en/products/statplus/content/help/analysis_basic_statistics_two_sample_z-test.html

@Paul thank you, that answered my question. I had no idea that this extension for the z-score existed.
